# Windows 2008 R2 WDS

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, wds

I am trying to test the Windows deployment services in Windows 2008 R2. I am able to get an IP when my desktop PXE boots but then I get PXE-E32: TFTP open timeout.

Has anyone run into this? if so anyone know a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have DNS and WDS running on the same box, a patch from over last summer (the DNS exploit patch) can cause this to happen.  The fix for this is on [Johan Arwidmark's blog](http://www.deployvista.com/Default.aspx?tabid=70&EntryID=66).  Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on our Windows 2008 R2 Server.  The fix from Johan Arwidmark Blog worked.  I changed the range from 64001 - 65000 to 60000 - 65000

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the DNS patch, but the fix in the [Johan Arwidmark's blog](http://www.deployvista.com/Default.aspx?tabid=70&EntryID=66) isn't quite correct. The DNS patch causes the DNS process to bind to 2500 random ports when the service starts, which has a small chance of overlapping with the WDS port range.

To fix this, you need to increase the size of the port range for WDS to something larger then 2500 ports to make sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The article (blog) is updated to reflect new configuration options in Windows Server 2008 R2, as well as an explaination to the problem and updated instructions for Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008.

http://www.deployvista.com/Default.aspx?tabid=70&EntryID=66

Regards / Johan Arwidmark